# angular 2 unit test: There is no directive with "exportAs"

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ng2-bootstrap

I've created a component that exports a bootstrap modal:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss'],
  exportAs: 'modal'
})
```

And then on the parent component i consume it as follows:

```
<app-modal #modalHandler="modal"></app-modal>
```

The issue is when i write a unit test for the parent component using NO_ERROR_SCHEMA, karma fails with the following error:

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "modal"
```

It resolves only after i import the modal component to the the parent component in TestBed.

Seems like NO_ERROR_SCHEMA doesn't silence this error. Anyway I can avoid this error without importing the child modal to my parents unit test?

Comment: Did you import ModalModule in more than one submodules.

Comment: No, only one. How is it related to the question ?

Comment: you need to mock the module with all the dependent modules in your unit testing as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It resolves only after i import the modal component to the the parent
>   component in TestBed.

It should be imported. Because in TestBed you just created a empty Module with your parent component. While doing this it try to compile and execute your parent template as well. There it is defied as

```
<app-modal #modalHandler="modal"></app-modal>
```

So it will look for an object which is defined as export as `modal`.

In test case since your module is empty and does not import that `app-modal`, so your parent template can not be initialized.

So you need to

> import the modal component to the the parent component in TestBed

This is how TestBed works. You need to import which is required you to test your component independently.

**Note:**

Generaly we use following line to create a testing module in spec fiel itself.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
});
```

So it is not using that module in which your parent component exists. Rather it is creating a testing module in run-time.

Comment: Thanks, just thought there is a way without it. Since the modal may have it's dependencies, and i don't event want to test it's functionality in the parent component...